# #1130 - Host ‘localhost’ is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, privileges, mysql-error-1130

I issued a command of:

```
DROP USER 'root'@'localhost'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'root'@'%';
```

...in PhpMyAdmin. Immediately after the execution, I was forced out PhpMyAdmin.  I got:

error

> #1130 - Host 'localhost' is not
>   allowed to connect to this MySQL
>   server,

how to resolve my problem?

Comment: Were you issuing the command as 'root'@'localhost'? Commands are executed in the order you enter them, so DROP USER would have been executed first, and if you dropped the user you're trying to issue commands as, that's why you were "forced out of phpMyAdmin," and your second command (GRANT) would never be executed.

I hope you have access to another user with GRANT privileges.

Comment: You are right. The first command was executed but the second command was not executed. I don't have access to another user. Maybe I have, but I can not remember.

Comment: @Steven: What version of MySQL are you using?  `mysqladmin` from the command line was recognized for me, using 4.1.x.  I found the mysqladmin.exe in Program Files\MySQL 4.1\Bin - maybe you'll have to navigate in the command prompt to the bin directory in order to be able to run it?  Wasn't the case for me.

Comment: Mine is MySQL 5.1. And the directory is E:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin>mysqld, when I enter E:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin>mysqld, I got Windows cannot find 'D:\Program'.Make sure you typed the name correctly,and then try again.To search for file,click the start button,and then click search

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the IP instead:

```
DROP USER 'root'@'127.0.0.1'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'root'@'%';
```

For more possibilities, see [this link](http://www.webyog.com/faq/content/23/36/en/i-get-error-1130-host-is-not-allowed-to-connect-or-access-denied-or-could-not-connect-.html).

To create the root user, seeing as MySQL is local & all, execute the following from the command line (Start > Run > "cmd" without quotes):

```
mysqladmin -u root password 'mynewpassword'
```

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqladmin.html), and [Lost root access in MySQL](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/lost-root-access-in-mysql-486785/).

Comment: From PHPMyAdmin, logged in as a user other than root with the appropriate permissions.

Comment: Now that's a problem.  Can you give some details on the setup - can you access the box MySQL is on, either by Remote Desktop or SSH/etc?

Comment: MySQL is on my local machine.

Comment: That's good news - windows, linux or other?  There's MySQL command line, or MySQL Administrator if you haven't installed it already: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html

Comment: I am using Windows, and I have installed MySQL Administrator.

Comment: The problem is, I can not log in MySQL Administrator.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw the comment about possibly not having a user with similar permissions.

Comment: Windows cannot find 'mysqladmin'.Make sure you typed the name correctly,and then try again.To search for file,click the start button,and then click search.

Comment: When I try to create the root user I got this error: mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server'
How can I solve this? I tried everything! :(

Answer (score 0):

Find the file "config.inc.php" under your phpMyAdmin directory and edit the following lines:

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';             // config, http, cookie`

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'root';               // MySQL user`

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'TYPE_YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE'; // MySQL password`

Note that the password used in the 'password' field must be the same for the MySQL root password. Also, you should check if root login is allowed in this line:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot']     = TRUE;        // true = allow root login
```

This way you have your root password set.

Answer (score -1):

Use this in your `my.ini` under

```
[mysqldump]
    user=root
    password=anything
```

Answer (score -2):

open your my.ini file, then add this

```
skip-grant-tables
```

line under

```
[mysqld]
```

so it should be like this

```
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
```

Then restart your mysql in xampp