# #1130 - Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: mysql, drupal, wamp, mysql-error-1130

Wamp get this message:

#1130 - Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Comment: possible duplicate of [#1130 - Host ‘localhost’ is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878458/1130-host-localhost-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)

Answer (score 1):

The same question has been posted on ServerFault

[#1130 - Host ‘localhost’ is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](https://serverfault.com/questions/92870/1130-host-localhost-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)

And on SO
[#1130 - Host ‘localhost’ is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878458/1130-host-localhost-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)