# unable to connect to other machine's mysql server using C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010

i need to connect to the other machine's mysql server using C# coding,below is my coding:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace c_mysql
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connection = "SERVER=192.168.1.5; Database=b2b; Uid=root;";
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connection);
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from area",con);
            MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("connection successfull");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("not connected...");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the ip address 192.168.1.5 is the ip address of other computer which is in LAN,I am able to connect through 192.168.1.5/phpmyadmin in url bar but when connecting through C# coding it says,

```
Host 'pc1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

Pc 1 is my pc on which i am coding.

please help me.

Comment: Allow mysql access to this user for '%' ips.

Comment: i allowed it but nothing happened

Comment: check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878458/1130-host-localhost-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server

Comment: would you please tell me what to do to the point rather referencing to other solutions..?

Comment: It has to do with your mysql server not permitting `root` user to connect from other ips other than local.. solution is to provide access to your ip for this user on mysql server...and I just provided you link for how to do that... and btw `tell me what to do` is not a developer's attitude !

Answer (score 0):

### Enable Remote Root Access to MySql. [click here for more details](http://benrobb.com/2007/01/15/howto-remote-root-access-to-mysql/)

Snippet taken from above:

create a new HOST for root and allow root to login from anywhere.

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit
```