# 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, windows, xampp

When I tried to connect to my `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` the following error appeared:

```
#1130 - Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

I tried to connect to MySQL from command line and the same error appeared as well.

I used root as user, there are many suggestions that tell to do some scripts from MySQL, but I can't log in MySQL even though with root user. I have a root access but I can't log in because of that error, that error appears when I try to log in.

[image: Screenshot of Windows terminal]

Comment: Seems like a very clear answer to your problem. You cannot connect to the database you're trying to connect with.

Comment: Show your mysql.users table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Host 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)

Comment: If you have root access, you can reset the permissions this user has to access the database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [#1130 - Host ‘localhost’ is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878458/1130-host-localhost-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)

Comment: @halfer how I can do that? actually I have the root access.

Comment: Use the `CREATE USER` syntax, [docs are here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-users.html). Log on a root (or another administrator user) to do so.

Comment: I have a root access but I can't log in because of that error.

That error appears when I try to log in.

Comment: You can't log in as root either? To be absolutely clear, are you saying that MySQL has locked you out completely? I don't think it is possible to do that to the root account, but please clarify.

Comment: (If you are replying to someone, then use their handle e.g. @halfer for me, otherwise your response will likely be missed).

Comment: A couple of things to try: use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`, that might work. Also, do a search for "start MySQL without root password" to create a new user account. I think you might have deleted the root user, and need to reset it.

Answer (score 1):

You could start MySQL with the `--skip-grant-tables` option

```
service mysqld stop
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

Then allow the user you're logging in as access from localhost:

```
grant all on <db>.<table> to '<user>'@'localhost' identified by password('<password>')
```

Then start MySQL normally:

```
service mysqld start
```

Replace all the `<word>` placeholders above with the actual settings. If you have root access you can just log in with the root user and run the grant line.

Comment: This is suitable for Ubuntu (for which +1) but I don't think we know what OS the user is on.

Comment: Yep, though unfortunately the OP is on Windows.