# error message while connecting to phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

i can't connect to PhpMyAdmin on my local server as shown bellow, it shows me the message "#1130 - Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server", i think the problem is with MySql, someone can help pleas ?

[image]

Comment: Is your WAMPServer on a different PC to where you are trying to run  phpMyAdmin from?

Comment: No sir @RiggsFolly i'm on the same PC

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you running? And what version of Apache.

Answer (score 2):

try given link

[#1130 - Host ‘localhost’ is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878458/1130-host-localhost-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server][1])

Comment: i'm a beginner to this, can you show me all the steps to do that sir ?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it might be an IPV4/IPV6 issue. Modern browser will use either, why the decide to use IPV4 or IPV6 address ranges, I dont know yet.

You can test this theory by launching phpMyAdmin like this `127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin` if that works and `::1/phpmyadmin` does not, then the problem is probably related to phpMyAdmin not being allowed to be run from the `::1` IPV6 address.

First make sure you have these entries in your HOSTS file `\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
::1  localhost
```

These entries will associate the domain name localhost with both the IPV4 (127.0.0.1) and IPV6(::1) loopback ip address's i.e. connect to this machine when you see the domain name `localhost`.

If you have to change the HOSTS file you then need to reboot or run these 2 commands from a command windows that is started using "Run as Administrator" to refresh the `dnscache` and pick up your changes.

```
net stop dnscache
net start dnscache
```

Next check the Alias settings for phpMyAdmin.

Edit the `\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf` file.

Make sure that both `127.0.0.1` and `::1` are allowed to connect to Apache

If you are using Apache 2.2.x then look for this section and make sure it contains this in the `Allow from` line

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
```

If you are using Apache 2.2.4 then look for this section and make sure it contains this in the `Require` line. If you still have the old Apache 2.2 syntax in here, remove it and use this instead.

```
Require local
```

The `Require local` covers both `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and `::1` in Apache 2.4

Comment: sorry sir, the problem is that i can't even launch Phpmyadmin the first screen i got while openening localhost/phpmyadmin or 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin is the screen above.

Comment: In that case are you runing WAMPServer? If so what version. Also have you changed the MySQL `root` user in any way like adding a password.

Answer (score 0):

I would help, but I can't read the text in your image and there is no code either.

Comment: Thanx sir, the message is "#1130 - Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server "

Comment: Try `Right Click -> View Image`